# increasing accuracy of binary logistic regression by reducing type II error?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, biostatistics, accuracy, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am to use binary logistic regression predict a deadly disease from 109 cases out of 385 patients. If during the preliminary diagnosis all patients were sent to the expert doctor for secondary diagnosis, the accuracy rate of the model is 109/385 = 28%. But sending all patients to the expert doctor is costly and not all hospitals have an expert doctor. So the model should increase this prediction accuracy.

I also have chosen 13 risk factors to help to predict this disease: 3 numerical and 10 binary. I run a binary logistic regression with these risk factors in SPSS. In the classification table, after reducing the cut-off from 0.5 down to 0.05, I get no typeII error: all patients who have the diseases have been correctly diagnosed. (edit: in SPSS binary logistic regression report, there is a classification table where I observe results)

However, the accuracy of the model does not improve much in this case. 30-35% from base 28%.

I added the interaction terms 2-way, 3-way, the result does not seem to change much. Is this problem inherently not possible to solve with multivariate logistic regression?

How can I improve the accuracy of the model? I want to keep the typeII error as close to zero as possible or zero, at the same time I want to improve the accuracy away from 28% (the base accuracy rate).

Biostatistic experts are welcome to reply.

Comment: Logistic regression models don't really have an accuracy, they output a probability.  How are you deciding how to threshold those probabilities to make class assignments?  Have you experimented with how you set the threshold?

Comment: In SPSS, there is a classification table. Yes, I reduced the cut-off from 0.5 down to 0.10 and eventually zeroed out the typeII error.
I am trying to figure out if the multivariate (binary) logistic regression with 13 risk factors can make a significantly better prediction. Also, I am trying to figure out from a list of many risk factors, which are more related to this diagnosis.

Comment: Obviously, if I set the cut-off at 0.5, the accuracy of the model increases, but type II error increases too and some patients are not diagnosed even tough they should have been. So I am trying to figure out if there is a way to improve accuracy without sacrificing type II error rate.